# Pandas: find the first couple of timestamp indices that are the same given two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have the following `df1`:

```
                      Value
2020-06-02 00:00:00   17
2020-06-03 00:00:00   10
2020-06-05 00:00:00   86
```

and the following `df2`:

```
                      Value
2020-06-01 00:00:00   16
2020-06-04 00:00:00   9
2020-06-05 00:00:00   86
```

and I know that the two dataframes have different length. How can I find the day of the first and the last couple of indices where `df1.index == df2.index`?

In my example, the day of the first matching couple would be `2020-06-05 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and then use minimal and maximal values:

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
min1 = idx.min()
max1 = idx.max()
```

Comment: Uhm I noticed that this is fairly slow given two dataframes of less than 100,000 rows. Is there anything I can do to increase the speed?

Comment: @Zizzipupp - Are index sorted?

Comment: @Zizzipupp - Is possible use [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) ? like `idx = numpy.intersect1d(df1.index, df2.index)` ?

Comment: Yes, but it requires to turn `min1` and `max1` into strings before using them as slicers in `df1.loc[min1:max1]`. If you don't do this, you may get `KeyError: "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label:...`

Comment: @Zizzipupp - Last should be used `min1 = pd.Timestamp(idx.min())` ?

Comment: Correct. The exact sequence is `str(pd.Timestamp(idx.min()))`.